# iOS, testFlight, app can't connect to the Internet

Tags: ios, networking, testflight

I installed testFlight, added app to the iTunes connect, and downloaded it using testFlight.
My test app can't connect to the internet. But If I upload my app through the cable - Internet works.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, on iOS 9.2.1 on iPhone 6+

Comment: Did you manage to solve this ? I'm facing the same problem...

Comment: @VincentMonteil you was be able to solve it? someone?

Comment: Hi @JuanSalvadorPortugal , I wasn't notified of your comments. Common solution is App Transport Security in info.plist . In my case, there was an error in my request, causing it to return null value, which couldn't be handled by my script. Returned var was empty and nothing was displayed. It seemed like it couldn't access internet but it was actually a data problem.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue but rebuilt to my phone and it did not connect to the internet either.

Seems to be an issue with the App Transport Security, new in iOS9

Answer (score 1):

Feedback :

Common solution is App Transport Security in info.plist .

In my case, there was an error in my request, causing it to return null value, which couldn't be handled by my script. Returned var was empty and nothing was displayed. It seemed like it couldn't access internet but it was actually a data problem.
Request corrected with null handling => App working fine now.

Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 0):

Just enable mobile data in your testflight app settings.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer. For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using TestFlight on iPad

I uninstalled the Antivirus and worked

Thanks to [Chathuranga Jayawardhana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67896069/4508758)