# flutter: Exception : SocketException: Connection failed only on iOS Simulator

Tags: flutter, dart, ios-simulator, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

I am getting the following error when I try to invoke a REST API with dart HTTP module, this happens **only** on iOS Simulator, tried running the same code on an iOS Device and Android Emulator, working fine on both of them.

This is what I am getting when I log the exception,

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           28.0s
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51060/OGZYZc5p7EM=/ws
Syncing files to device iPhone 12 Pro Max...
flutter: Exception : SocketException: Connection failed, address = my.domain.api.net, port = 443
```

iOS Development tools : `XCode Version 12.5 (12E262)`

flutter doctor output :

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on macOS 11.2.3 20D91 darwin-x64, locale en-LK)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.56.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Tried to access my API URL with Safari on Simulator and it is working fine too, apart from the flutter exception, I am not getting any other information/logs.

Comment: Facing the same. Did you found any workaround?

Comment: @TapasPal nope, still having the issue, I have reported this on flutter github project as well, but still waiting for any reply.  I was facing this issue when i tried to access REST api with self signed SSL certificate, using this method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59622087/flutter-https-with-self-signed-certificate, turns out APIs with proper SSL certificates seems to be working without any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for my issue has to do something with Sophos Antivirus, I have removed Sophos and was able to solve the issue. I was getting a similar socket exception when I try to use `flutter pub get`, but only with one of my internet connections, it is working fine when I switch to another connection, I tried to get `flutter pub get` working by removing the Sophos, and it solves both `flutter pub get` issue and the connection issue with the iOS simulator.

Comment: thanks a lot! I uninstalled my avast antivirus and worked